# How to get the data in PowerBI graph using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, powerbi

How to get the data? when I hover the graph, the data are showing Ad sales and Ad Spend. Only one Ad sales is showing. What is the best approach of getting data?

```html
<g role="listbox" aria-label="Plot area" aria-live="polite" class="mainGraphicsContext setFocusRing" tabindex="0" focusable="true" pbi-focus-tracker-idx="4">
  <path class="line" d="M10,32.74504916281946L53.59311166071265,32.75704678802555L97.1862233214253,35.65811560366859L140.77933498213795,29.794149851813685L184.3724466428506,27.080717438272877L227.96555830356328,25.30021605667766L271.5586699642759,28.72240145414262L315.1517816249886,26.195238897052764L358.7448932857012,27.00679485068013L402.3380049464139,26.56327008532564L445.93111660712657,28.675669896949717L489.52422826783925,36.02464036366446L533.1173399285518,22.04296303514015L576.7104515892645,27.504776998248147L620.3035632499772,28.213239456718878L663.8966749106899,37.95961520486397L707.4897865714024,25.569662274422924L751.0828982321151,12.40761105100989L794.6760098928278,11.770972940746079"
    style="stroke: rgb(255, 99, 0); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 3; stroke-linejoin: round;"></path>
  <path class="line" d="M10,72.29998204410552L53.59311166071265,72.78037126143857L97.1862233214253,73.56588752627782L140.77933498213795,70.91160394301319L184.3724466428506,70.2662177885408L227.96555830356328,70.27319039942292L271.5586699642759,70.94981342023907L315.1517816249886,70.77908129544518L358.7448932857012,70.75805586077905L402.3380049464139,69.81753888643858L445.93111660712657,70.01474110809976L489.52422826783925,71.27097316869333L533.1173399285518,67.68272557409315L576.7104515892645,67.12250641828113L620.3035632499772,67.4932922182605L663.8966749106899,72.35342796733306L707.4897865714024,67.20621002947237L751.0828982321151,64.94867661356142L794.6760098928278,64.93905699299259"
    style="stroke: rgb(102, 102, 102); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 3; stroke-linejoin: round;"></path>
  <path class="interactivity-line sub-selectable ungroupable-sub-selection" data-sub-selection-object-name="lines" d="M10,32.74504916281946L53.59311166071265,32.75704678802555L97.1862233214253,35.65811560366859L140.77933498213795,29.794149851813685L184.3724466428506,27.080717438272877L227.96555830356328,25.30021605667766L271.5586699642759,28.72240145414262L315.1517816249886,26.195238897052764L358.7448932857012,27.00679485068013L402.3380049464139,26.56327008532564L445.93111660712657,28.675669896949717L489.52422826783925,36.02464036366446L533.1173399285518,22.04296303514015L576.7104515892645,27.504776998248147L620.3035632499772,28.213239456718878L663.8966749106899,37.95961520486397L707.4897865714024,25.569662274422924L751.0828982321151,12.40761105100989L794.6760098928278,11.770972940746079"
    style="stroke-width: 10; stroke-linejoin: round;"></path>
  <path class="interactivity-line sub-selectable ungroupable-sub-selection" data-sub-selection-object-name="lines" d="M10,72.29998204410552L53.59311166071265,72.78037126143857L97.1862233214253,73.56588752627782L140.77933498213795,70.91160394301319L184.3724466428506,70.2662177885408L227.96555830356328,70.27319039942292L271.5586699642759,70.94981342023907L315.1517816249886,70.77908129544518L358.7448932857012,70.75805586077905L402.3380049464139,69.81753888643858L445.93111660712657,70.01474110809976L489.52422826783925,71.27097316869333L533.1173399285518,67.68272557409315L576.7104515892645,67.12250641828113L620.3035632499772,67.4932922182605L663.8966749106899,72.35342796733306L707.4897865714024,67.20621002947237L751.0828982321151,64.94867661356142L794.6760098928278,64.93905699299259"
    style="stroke-width: 10; stroke-linejoin: round;"></path>
  <g class="cat"></g>
  <g class="cat"></g>
  <g class="selected-markers"></g>
  <circle class="focus-element setFocusRing" tabindex="0" focusable="true" role="option" aria-label="Week Starting in: Sunday, September 05, 2021. Ad Sales 50,497.72." cx="10" cy="32.74504916281946" r="3.5" style="fill: none;"></circle>
</g>
```

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.

Comment: Your example code type XML. You can file upload XML in Power BI. Than parse the xml and what you want to need fields in file.